# flex atoi(yytext) does not assign value to a variable

Tags: flex-lexer

I am making simple lexer using flex. I want to read yytext value and save it as an integer in variable t, but when I compile it it shows me following error:

> error: stray ‘\35’ in program
> t = atoi(yytext);

Here is the code:

```
    %{
     #include "global.h"//contains stdlib 
    
     int t=0;
    %}

    DIGIT   [0-9]

%%


{DIGIT} {
        
        printf("found an integer, = %d \n", atoi( yytext));//this compiles without errors
        t = atoi(yytext); //here I have error
        
        //...rest of code

        
    }

        
%%
   main(){

         yylex();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically:

> error: stray ‘\35’ in program

are connect to the use of wrong quoation marks "

Example:

```
`a` ‘a’  instead of 'a' 
”a“ ...  instead of "a"
```

See if this appears in your "global.h"